# How to repeat styles in React-native

Tags: react-native

I have a row of controls/buttons, and each will have the same style.  Is there a more efficient way (or in other words, a way to use less code) to apply the styles without having to use the style attribute on every component?

```
<View>
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.control}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Left</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.control}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Right</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.control}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Up</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.control}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Down</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

I thought about creating an array of objects for each control and mapping over it to repeat the controls, but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it.

Comment: What do you mean by efficient - CPU or productivity?

Comment: @ide, by efficiency I mean a way to do this using less code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<View>
  {['Left', 'Right', 'Up', 'Down'].map((direction) => {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.control}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{direction}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  })}
</View>
```

Comment: That works for the specific question I asked, so I'll probably end up accepting that answer, but I didn't want to do it that way is because I'll need to attach a different onPress function to each control, so the array it's mapping over would be more complex than that. I was hoping there would be a way to apply a style to a parent and have it determine the style for children (kind of like CSS), but I imagine that's not possible. I should probably just create a custom component and then pass the onPress functions through the props.

Comment: This is the pretty basic way to replicate anything with React, but you're right, if you have a more complex structure the best solution is to create a component indeed.